# Flatpickr: Trigger event only after selecting a date range

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, date-range, flatpickr

I'm working on flat-pickr. And now to the config part. I have 1 fields date_range. I want to trigger a event only after user choses date_range.

```
 <flat-pickr
          class="form-control shadow-none"
          name="date_range"
          :value="date_range"
          @input="$emit('update:filter', $event.target.value)"
          @onClose="$emit('updateTrigger')"
          :config="configRange"
          placeholder="Select date range"
        />
```

Here I want to emit updateTrigger only after user chooses a date_range, not after chosing a single date. Here It triggers the updateTrigger after closing the datepicker, but on filter, I only get the one date .

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `selectedDates.length === 2` in the `onChange` event. So put to flatpickr `@on-change="updateTrigger"` and then make function:

```
const updateTrigger = (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
    if (selectedDates.length === 2) {
        $emit('update:filter', selectedDates);          
    }
};
```